# Refresh a DVT Graph selection on event in Oracle ADF

Tags: graph, oracle-adf

I have a requirement in which i have a af:table. The af:table is used as a partial trigger to a dvt:graph which is a pie graph(pg1).

The pie Graph(pg2) in turn is also used as a partial trigger to another pie graph(pg2).

Now my requirement was to select the row in af:table which should update the pg1 to show data as per row data. Next when i clicked on one of the slices of the pie graph, the graph pg2 should get updated to bring data based on the selected slice value.

Now when i click on the row of af:Table, and then lets say i have selected slice 1(value x) of pg1, then the pg2 gets updated perfectly.

but when i select another row of the table, the pg1 data gets updated but the slice which was selected remains selected, thus even though it updates the data in the pg2 graph, it updates the data based on the previously selected slice with updated value(say y).

i need to refresh the pg1 graph in such a way that even its selections a removed.

i have tried partial triggers to no avail.

I have also tried to manually reset the graph binding component. but couldn't find the exact code for it.(if any please help.)

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting ChangeEventPolicy="ppr" for graph node in your PageDef